# individual Table borders?

Tags: flutter

I would like to use a Table to display a regular grid with square cells to display a calculation like this one:

[image: Multiplication]

Is it possible in flutter to create the thick lines for some of the cells by just using a Table and its border properties?
Or do I need a Container with a BoxDecoration in the "overlined" cells (and maybe in the cells above if I want the thick lines right at the border)?